# Proofing That $\int_0^a(f(x) + f^{-1}(x))dx \geq a^2$ for $a > 0$

Tags: integration, functions

Hello everyone $f(x)$ is a increasing function that for $f(0) = 0$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ is  the opposite function of $f(x)$

How can I proof that $\int_0^a(f(x) + f^{-1}(x))dx \geq a^2$ for $a > 0$

Thanks!

Comment: Surely there must be something missing. How about the case $a = 1$? You'll get $0 \ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you I fixed that.

Comment: My idea is that if $f$ is differentiable, either $f'(x) \geqslant 1$, either $f^{-1} '(f(x)) \geqslant 1$, so you would have one of the two terms $\geqslant 1$... This is just an idea, but maybe you can generalize this for inscreasing functions ? Also a reparametrization with $y=f(x)$ would give something ?

Comment: The function is either strictly increasing or decreasing.

Comment: How the fact that $f(0) = 0$ help me?

Comment: An idea (assuming $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous): Define $g(x) = \int_0^x(f(t)+f^{-1}(t))dt - x^2$. If you can show that $g'(x) \ge 0$, you're done. $g'(x)$ turns out to be $f(x) + f^{-1}(x) - 2x$. So, you are done if you can show that $x$ is less than the average of $f$ and its inverse. (So far we haven't used that $f(0) = 0$.)

Comment: It has to do with the distribution of $f(x)$ on the both side of the line $f(x)=x$.

Comment: How can I draw the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) + f^{-1}(x) dx $
$=\int_{0}^{a} y + f^{-1}(x) dx$

Let, $f^{-1}(a)=a'$

So, $\int_{0}^{a}  f^{-1}(x) dx = aa' - \int_{0}^{a'} y dx$

And replacing this to its original expression we get,

$=\int_{0}^{a} y + f^{-1}(x) dx = aa' +\int_{a'}^{a} y dx$

Now,  $\int_{a'}^{a} y dx \geq (a-a')f(a')=(a-a')a=a^2-aa'$

So, $=\int_{0}^{a} y + f^{-1}(x) dx = aa' +\int_{a'}^{a} y dx \geq aa'+a^2-aa'=a^2$.

We are done.

Comment: Thank You very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Proof assuming that $f$ is smooth: We can write the left side as $\int_0^{a}f(x)dx+\int _0^{f^{-1}(a)} yf'(y)dy$ (by the substitution $y=f^{-1}(x)$ in the second term).

Now integrate the second term by parts to get $\int_0^{a}f(x)dx+ yf(y)|_0^{f^{-1}(a)}-\int_0^{f^{-1}(a)}f(y)dy$. Note that $\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{a}f(y)dy \geq f(f^{-1}(a)) (a-f^{-1}(a)$. This gives the desired inequality.

I have assumed in this argument that $f^{-1}(a) \leq a$ but there is  a similar argument when $f^{-1}(a) >a$.

Comment: Thank you very much but I think its too advanced to me there is a simpler solution?